# Downloading multiple files in REST using jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Please suggest how we should download multiple files (for example two images and a jar file) in a REST application.

I was able to successfully write the service to download a single file using **"application/octet-stream"**

```
@POST
@Path("/attachment")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces("application/octet-stream")   
public Response getAttachment(JAXBElement<AggRequest> req) {

        File file=new File("file.txt")
        return Response.ok(file).header("content-disposition",
                        "attachment; filename = " + filename).build();
```

Now I want to return multiple files from this method. What is the standard approach to doing this? Please suggest the standard MIME type for `@produces`.

Any suggestions or link will be appreciated.

Comment: Can we use @Produces("multipart/form-data"). is it the right approach.I was able to download mutiple files using "mutiplepart"

Comment: You can use two approaches - 1) Write a JavaScript script or Applet to download the files one by one or 2) ZIP all the files